# Aspnetzero - Publishing .NET Core 2.0 version question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I just published my Aspnetzero solution to my hosting provider site. 
I have multiple apps setup on my website. They are located in the example.com/apps/app1 folder structure.
So my aspnetzero site is on **example.com/apps/aspnetzeroapp** folder.

As I expected, this is breaking all of the URL references (Images, nav menu links etc.) on my published app.
I have updated the appsettings.json files with the URLs as shown below.

```
"App": {
"WebSiteRootAddress": "https://example.com/apps/aspnetzeroapp/", 
"RedirectAllowedExternalWebSites":"https://example.com/apps/aspnetzeroapp/"},
```

**Question**: Can someone tell me all the changes, within the aspnetzero template code, that I need to make in order for my app to work given the above folder structure?

**Update:** I found [this thread](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10198&hilit=publish%20subfolder) on the ABP support forum. I am having all the same issues with images and API endpoints. In that thread there is a link to a GIT code repo for a fix that was implemented by the ABP team. I cannot see it as I don't have an active license. Could that solution apply to my issue?

Comment: The issue was fixed with more than 3000 line of changes. The basic idea is to introduce a attribute "appBaseUrl" in "ApplicationComponentBase" and use this attribute in all the references.

Comment: @ryan.c I scanned my entire solution for "ApplicationComponentBase" and did not find any results. Can you provide any more details or specifics?

Comment: It should be AppComponentBase instead. Basically the parent component which all other components derived from.

Comment: Thanks for that info. If I have some more time, I may try this out at a later date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided on the easier option. I setup a new domain and deployed my app at root of the new domain. Its all working fine now!